# When error 1224: ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE occurs?

Tags: c++, winapi, createfile

I want to really understand when the `ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE` occurs. So I wrote some snippets. To reproduce the error. But it did not work. Please help me fix my code

**Process 1:**

```
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("C:\\test\\full.exe", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
        OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return GetLastError();

    HANDLE hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, NULL);
    if (hMapFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return GetLastError();

    mapHandles.push_back(hMapFile);

    viewHandles.push_back(MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0));
```

I am Halting the process and I have not closed any view of the map and file handles yet in this process so that when the other process tries to open the file. I thought error 1224 will be thrown.

**Process 2:**

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("C:\\test\\full.exe", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
    OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    cout << "Error Code : " << GetLastError() << endl;

char buffer[1025];
DWORD bytesRead;

if (!ReadFile(hFile, buffer, 1024, &bytesRead, 0))
    cout << "Error Code : " << GetLastError() << endl;
```

The `CreateFile` and `ReadFile` succeeds in the process 2.

Actually I am trying to handle this error 1224 separately. Which means when the file fails with error 32 I want to do something. and if the file fails with error 1224 I want to do something.

Now I must test those cases. In order to test those scenarios I should reproduce the error 1224.

Comment: Are you saying that the second process succeeds in opening the file? Well you do open it in *shared mode* in both processes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah If turn off shared mode then if failes with error 32, not with error 1224. I want to reproduce error 1224.

Comment: Then you should to tell us *why* you want that specific error. And what the *actual* problem you try to solve is ([related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude added some more description.

Comment: My (brief) research suggests that error 1224 occurs when you specify `CREATE_ALWAYS` in the call to CreateFile (in process #2) specifying that the file should be overwritten if it already exists.  I guess it might also happen if you call DeleteFile() on a file with a memory mapping open, assuming the original handle was opened with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thank you. It helped reproduce it. :)

Comment: Excellent.  When you have a chance, please post an answer, preferably including the "working" (i.e., failing in the desired way!) code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to really understand when the `ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE` occurs

if *really understand* let some extra info.

at first this error returned from kernel. so it was initially `NTSTATUS` error code, which than translated to win32 error by [`RtlNtStatusToDosError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680600(v=vs.85).aspx). api for reverse translation not exist - because it not uniquely, but possible yourself write code, which create reverse translation map. two `NTSTATUS` codes is translated to `ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE` : `STATUS_USER_MAPPED_FILE` and `STATUS_PURGE_FAILED`:

```
if (
    RtlNtStatusToDosError(STATUS_USER_MAPPED_FILE) != ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE
    ||
    RtlNtStatusToDosError(STATUS_PURGE_FAILED) != ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE 
    )
{
    __debugbreak();
}
```

for completely understand when this codes returned need look File System source code. we have [`fastfat`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/fastfat) example. if search for `STATUS_USER_MAPPED_FILE` - we can found that this code returned from 4 place:

- [`FatSupersedeOrOverwriteFile`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/create.c#L6305) - when we try call
  [`ZwCreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566424(v=vs.85).aspx) with `FILE_OVERWRITE_IF` or `FILE_SUPERSEDE`
  `CreateOption` or when we call [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) with `CREATE_ALWAYS`
- [`FatSetEndOfFileInfo`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/fileinfo.c#L4357) - when we call [`ZwSetInformationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567096(v=vs.85).aspx)
  with [`FileEndOfFileInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545780(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`SetEndOfFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531(v=vs.85).aspx) function
- [`FatSetValidDataLengthInfo`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/fileinfo.c#L4754)- when we call
  [`ZwSetInformationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567096(v=vs.85).aspx)    with
  [`FileValidDataLengthInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545873(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`SetFileValidData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365544(v=vs.85).aspx)
  function (*we need have `SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_PRIVILEGE` for this*)
- [`FatSetAllocationInfo`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/fileinfo.c#L4059) - when we use [`ZwSetInformationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567096(v=vs.85).aspx)
  with [`FileAllocationInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232076.aspx) (no win32 api shell)

and you can note common pattern here:

```
if (!MmCanFileBeTruncated())  return STATUS_USER_MAPPED_FILE;
```

about demo code for reproduce this error - for what you need **two** processes ?!? single routine in single process - more than enough.

```
void test()
{
    // for simplicity, i have access to this location as admin
    STATIC_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES(oa, "\\systemroot\\temp\\.tmp");
    HANDLE hFile, hSection, hFile2;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    LARGE_INTEGER AllocationSize = { PAGE_SIZE };
    NTSTATUS status;

    if (0 <= NtCreateFile(&hFile, FILE_GENERIC_WRITE|FILE_GENERIC_READ, &oa, &iosb, &AllocationSize, 0, 
        FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_OPEN_IF, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT, 0, 0))
    {
        status = NtCreateSection(&hSection, SECTION_MAP_READ|SECTION_MAP_WRITE, 0, &AllocationSize, PAGE_READWRITE, SEC_COMMIT, hFile);

        if (0 <= status)
        {
            PVOID BaseAddress = 0;
            SIZE_T ViewSize = 0;
            status = ZwMapViewOfSection(hSection, NtCurrentProcess(), &BaseAddress, 0, 0, 0, &ViewSize, ViewUnmap, 0, PAGE_READONLY);
            NtClose(hSection);

            if (0 <= status)
            {
                LARGE_INTEGER Eof = {};

                // SetEndOfFile win32 api
                status = ZwSetInformationFile(hFile, &iosb, &Eof, sizeof(Eof), FileEndOfFileInformation);

                if (status != STATUS_USER_MAPPED_FILE) __debugbreak();

                // no win32 api
                status = ZwSetInformationFile(hFile, &iosb, &Eof, sizeof(Eof), FileAllocationInformation);

                if (status != STATUS_USER_MAPPED_FILE) __debugbreak();

                // SetFileValidData win32 api
                // we need have SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME privilege, otherwise STATUS_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD
                status = ZwSetInformationFile(hFile, &iosb, &Eof, sizeof(Eof), FileValidDataLengthInformation);

                switch (status)
                {
                case STATUS_USER_MAPPED_FILE:
                case STATUS_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD:
                    break;
                default:  __debugbreak();
                }

                //CreateFileW(L"\\\\?\\c:\\windows\\temp\\.tmp", FILE_GENERIC_READ|FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, 0);

                status = NtCreateFile(&hFile2, FILE_GENERIC_WRITE|FILE_GENERIC_READ, &oa, &iosb, 0, 0, 
                    FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_OVERWRITE_IF, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT, 0, 0);

                if (status != STATUS_USER_MAPPED_FILE) __debugbreak();

                status = NtCreateFile(&hFile2, FILE_GENERIC_WRITE|FILE_GENERIC_READ, &oa, &iosb, 0, 0, 
                    FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_SUPERSEDE, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT, 0, 0);

                if (status != STATUS_USER_MAPPED_FILE) __debugbreak();

                ZwUnmapViewOfSection(NtCurrentProcess(), BaseAddress);
            }
        }

        NtClose(hFile);
    }
}
```

about `STATUS_PURGE_FAILED` - look like in can be returned when we call `WriteFile` - look [`here`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/write.c#L1276) - but i can not reproduce it in test. however very rarely this error can occur - [`"STATUS_PURGE_FAILED" error when you perform VM replications by using SCVMM in Windows Server 2012 R2`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3044457/-status-purge-failed-error-when-you-perform-vm-replications-by-using-scvmm-in-windows-server-2012-r2)

Answer (score 2):

`ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE` or error 1224 occurs when you try to delete or overwrite a file which has been mapped by other process.

#### Process #1

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("C:\\test\\full.exe", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
    OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return GetLastError();

HANDLE hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, NULL);
if (hMapFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return GetLastError();

mapHandles.push_back(hMapFile);

viewHandles.push_back(MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0));
```

#### Process #2

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("C:\\test\\full.exe", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    if(GetLastError() == 1224)
        // File has been mapped by other process
    else
        // some other issue
}
```

In Process #2, `CREATE_ALWAYS` tries to overwrite a file which has been mapped. So it ends up throwing error 1224.