# SetEndOfFile error 1224: ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE, even the file mapping closed successfully

Tags: c++, mfc, filesize, file-mapping

I'm writing a program which logs out to the file with file-mapping.
When I want to read the log, `Logger::Destroy()` is called so that the content writed on file-mapped-view could be flushed to the physical file.
The code is as follows:

```cpp
int Logger::Destroy() {
    if (m_lpMapAddress) {
        auto bRet = UnmapViewOfFile(m_lpMapAddress);
        // succeed
    }

    if (m_hMapFile) {
        auto bRet = CloseHandle(m_hMapFile);
        // succeed
        m_hMapFile = NULL;
    }

    int nSize = m_lpCurAddress - m_lpMapAddress;
    if (nSize > 0
        && nSize < (1024 * 1024 * 16 * 2))
    {
        DWORD dwPtr = SetFilePointer(m_hFile, nSize, 0, FILE_BEGIN);

        ///// Succeed
        // if (dwPtr == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
        //  DbgViewOut(__FUNCTION__ " SetFilePointer error: %d \n", GetLastError());

        //// Error occurs :  "SetEndOfFile returned : 0 1224"
        BOOL bRet = SetEndOfFile(m_hFile);
        DbgViewOut(__FUNCTION__ " SetEndOfFile returned : %d %d\n", bRet, GetLastError()); 
    
        ....
    }

    m_lpMapAddress = m_lpCurAddress = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

**The problem** is that `SetEndOfFile()` fails with `ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE`, even `CloseHandle(m_hMapFile)` succeed.
So I googled microsoft's manuals about file mapping and I comment some of them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle

> ***Closing a handle to a file mapping can succeed even when there are file views that are still open.*** For more information, see Closing a File Mapping Object.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/closing-a-file-mapping-object

> *When each process finishes using the file mapping object and has unmapped all views, it must close the file mapping object's handle and the file on disk by calling CloseHandle. ***These calls to CloseHandle succeed even when there are file views that are still open.*** However, leaving file views mapped causes memory leaks.*

It says that I can't believe the result of `CloseHandle()`.
And I can't find out the solution.

Anyone could help me? Thanks.

---

> Addition: I called `Logger::Destroy()` in `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`, can this affect to the trouble?
>
> > : I've tested this, lock doesn't affect to it.

---

> UPDATE: I've read [When error 1224: ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE occurs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41844842/when-error-1224-error-user-mapped-file-occurs). And I think there isn't a very big difference.
> I append the code of `Logger::Initialize()` which initializes the filemapping.
>  And also, `Logger::Initialize()` and `Logger::Destroy()` both are in same process&thread, no need to be shared with others.
>
> ```cpp
> int Logger::Initialize()
> {
>   m_hFile = CreateFileA(
>       m_zFileName.c_str()
>       , GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE
>       , FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE
>       , NULL                          
>       , CREATE_ALWAYS
>       , FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
>       , NULL);
>
>   if (m_hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
>       DbgViewOut(__FUNCTION__  " CreateFileA error: %d \n", GetLastError());
>       return -1;
>   }
>
>   m_hMapFile = CreateFileMappingA(
>       m_hFile
>       , NULL
>       , PAGE_READWRITE
>       , 0
>       , 1024 * 1024 * 16 * 2
>       , m_zMapKey.c_str());
>
>   if (!m_hMapFile) {
>       DbgViewOut(__FUNCTION__  " CreateFileMapping error: %d \n", GetLastError());
>       return -1;
>   }
>
>   m_hMapFile = OpenFileMappingA(FILE_MAP_WRITE, TRUE, m_zMapKey.c_str());
>   if (m_hMapFile == NULL) {
>       DbgViewOut(__FUNCTION__ " OpenFileMapping error: %d \n", GetLastError());
>       return -1;
>   }
>
>   m_lpMapAddress = (BYTE*)MapViewOfFile(
>       m_hMapFile              // handle to mapping object
>       , FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS   // read/write
>       , 0                 // high-order 32 bits of file offset
>       , 0                 // low-order 32 bits of file offset
>       , 0);                // number of bytes
>   if (m_lpMapAddress == NULL) {
>       DbgViewOut(__FUNCTION__ " MapViewOfFile error: %d \n", GetLastError());
>       return -1;
>   }
>
>   m_lpCurAddress = m_lpMapAddress;
>
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: Related/dupe: [When error 1224: ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE occurs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41844842/when-error-1224-error-user-mapped-file-occurs)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your suggestion. I've read it carefully, I think the key point of it is that multi process and `CREATE_ALWAYS`. But in my case, the `Logger::Destroy()`  is only for one process & thread. There is no need to be shared with others for the log file. I append code of `Logger::Initialize()` and please give me your opinion in details for that.

Comment: Why is `Logger::Initialize()` calling both `CreateFileMappingA()` and `OpenFileMappingA()` for the same mapping? You don't need the latter, get rid of it. You are leaking the 1st open handle. Also, if you don't intend to share the mapping, you should not be assigning a kernel name to it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Wow, thanks. It has solved ;). The problem was that I used both `CreateFileMappingA()` and `OpenFileMappingA()`. I also remove last argument - `m_zMapKey`  which is unnecessary. I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.

The problem was that I called `OpenFileMappingA()` after `CreateFileMappingA()`, so the `m_hMapFile` returned by `CreateFileMappingA()` is leaking.
I've removed `OpenFileMappingA()` and the problem disappeared.

I used to know that it must be once opened after create handle, and I used to do that in memory sharing between processes, monthes ago.
But during this arguement, I've realized that it's unecessary open handle after creating.

Thank you very much, @RemyLebeau, for your detailed suggestion.

```cpp
int Logger::Initialize()
{
    m_hFile = CreateFileA(
        m_zFileName.c_str()
        , GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE
        , FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE
        , NULL                          
        , CREATE_ALWAYS
        , FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
        , NULL);

    if (m_hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        DbgViewOut(__FUNCTION__  " CreateFileA error: %d \n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }


    m_hMapFile = CreateFileMappingA(
        m_hFile
        , NULL
        , PAGE_READWRITE
        , 0
        , LINM_LOGGER_FILE_MAXSIZE * 2
        , m_zMapKey.c_str());

    if (!m_hMapFile) {
        DbgViewOut(__FUNCTION__  " CreateFileMapping error: %d \n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

//// This was the solution - CreateFileMappingA & OpenFileMappingA mustn't be used for same process or thread.
//
//  m_hMapFile = OpenFileMappingA(FILE_MAP_WRITE, TRUE, m_zMapKey.c_str());
//  if (m_hMapFile == NULL) {
//      DbgViewOut(__FUNCTION__ " OpenFileMapping error: %d \n", GetLastError());
//      return -1;
//  }

    m_lpMapAddress = (BYTE*)MapViewOfFile(
        m_hMapFile              // handle to mapping object
        , FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS   // read/write
        , 0                 // high-order 32 bits of file offset
        , 0                 // low-order 32 bits of file offset
        , 0);                // number of bytes
    if (m_lpMapAddress == NULL) {
        DbgViewOut(__FUNCTION__ " MapViewOfFile error: %d \n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    m_lpCurAddress = m_lpMapAddress;

    return 0;
}
```