# Embarcadero C++ Builder XE8: Can't build project on Google Drive folder

Tags: c++builder

Our team uses a shared Google Drive map to store our projects. In the past we used 'Backup & Sync' to synchronize and map it to a local logical drive letter on windows. This worked fine.
But recently 'Backup & Sync' was discontinued and replaced by 'Google Drive for Desktop'. This works in a different way. Everything is basically stored in the cloud with an option for offline access.

Unfortunatly not all software works well with this though. One particular issue we have is with C++ Builder. When trying to build a project it fails with the following messages:

```
[ilink32 Warning] Warning: Failed to create state file H:/My Drive/Foobar/Win32/Debug/Foobar.ils (error code 1224)
[ilink32 Warning] Warning: Unable to perform incremental link - performing full link...
[ilink32 Warning] Warning: Failed to create state file H:/My Drive/Foobar/Win32/Debug/Foobar.ils (error code 1224)
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
```

I'm looking for a fix or workaround.

Comment: Error 1224 is `ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE`: "*The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.*" In other words, an app somewhere (Google?) has the file opened and mapped with `CreateFileMapping()` (and presumably `MapViewOfFile/Ex()`), hence the error when you try to open the same file. See [When error 1224: ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE occurs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41844842/). Is there a reason why you are using Google to share projects, instead of a proper version control system?

Comment: About the reason why: We're a small company with just 2 developpers, and we usually don't work at the same project at the same time. Before we used a network drive for our work folders. Google Drive is convenient for working at home. So far, it suited us well.