# Why Does a Program Compile and Run Successfully But Then Fail to Compile and Link?

Tags: c++builder

I'm experiencing a frustrating problem with C++Builder 12. I can successfully load and build a pre-existing project using <kbd>Shift+F9</kbd>.

However, sometimes if I invoke <kbd>Shift+F9</kbd> again, I get this error message:

> [ilink32 Error] Fatal: Could not open .\Win32\Release\MyProg.exe (error code 1224)

This error has happened with VCL projects and console projects, and with all combinations of 32/64-bit and Release/Debug.

Comment: I think that error code means the MyProg.exe is already open .  You will get an error if you try and link a project that is running at the time, since Windows exclusively locks any running executable

Comment: also are you running the project out of cloud storage? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70435340/embarcadero-c-builder-xe8-cant-build-project-on-google-drive-folder

Comment: I'm confident the program is not already running. Ctrl+F2 doesn't do anything and nothing suspicious is listed in Task Manager. However, all of my files normally reside in OneDrive. I moved the project to an area that is only on the local drive, and then this happens: 1) Initial compile and run is successful; 2) Invoking Shift+F9 immediately after running the program always results in the link error, but all subsequent invocations of Shift+F9 are successful. This is a new problem with C++Builder 12.

Comment: It might be taking a while to exit the process on the first one, after you have closed the main window

Comment: Does it happen only with one specific project or with all projects? Even with a new project without any code? What happens when you clean your project before compiling again (via IDE or by deleting the Win32 folder)? Double check if your path is really out of scope of any cloud syncing tools. Also try tools like Sysinternal's Process Monitor (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor) to check if any other installed tools are scanning/watching/blocking new executable files (Malware checker, Anti-Virus, ...)

Comment: I've created both a default VCL project and a default console project; no code was added; the only code is created by C++Builder. (Both projects are on the C: drive. OneDrive is not in the project path.) Each program compiles (Shift+F9) and runs. Attempting to use Shift+F9 immediately after the program closes results in the reported link error code 1224. Attempting to use Shift+F9 immediately after that error results in an error-free compile. AND if, instead of using Shift+F9 immediately after the program closes, I invoke Project > Clean MyProject, I get an error-free compile with Shift+F9.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that my use of Webroot SecureAnywhere was causing the problem. Disabling it eliminates the problem. I haven't found a way to adjust the settings of SecureAnywhere to allow it to continue to run but not interfere with C++Builder.

Comment: Ah, snake oil ([snake oil](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-12167/Webroot.html) because the antivirus program in fact exposes the largest attack surface on your computer, since it must open and inspect all file types) ... anyway: I would expect that any anti-virus program has a setting to not scan certain directories or trusted executables, partly for performance reasons and partly to work around false positives. Try to exclude the build directory in the scan/real time protection settings.